# How to write a pandoc reader with Python

Tags: python, pandoc

I've been searching for a way to write a pandoc reader (not a filter) with Python. But could not find any.

I mean a `Reader` as documented in [Text.Pandoc.Readers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.18/docs/Text-Pandoc-Readers.html)

There are examples for [Lua](https://pandoc.org/custom-readers.html) and of course for [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.18/docs/src/Text.Pandoc.Readers.html#Reader).

Is it possible to write a reader in python? Are there any working examples?

Comment: And the [pandoc python](https://boisgera.github.io/pandoc/) library doesn't support your use case? When you say "reader" do you just mean a program that can process the pandoc format or are you referring to something else? (Reader monad?)

Comment: @Souperman: I mean a `Reader` as documented in `Text.Pandoc.Readers`  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.18/docs/Text-Pandoc-Readers.html]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "reader" usually refers to any program that parses a file into pandoc's internal document representation. Both compiled-in readers written in Haskell as well as custom Lua readers create the document elements directly; this is not possible with any other method.

However, it would be possible to do all parsing and conversions in a separate program, and to pass the document representation as JSON:

```
my-reader file.txt | pandoc --from=json ...
```

Here, `my-reader` must emit the pandoc JSON format. Probably the most *pythonic* llibrary for that purpose would be [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/). The library is intended for use in a filter, but could as well be used to create a document and its components.

Comment: that's exactly what I was searching for: How to "inject" an initial AST into pandoc. Thanx a lot for the hint.